# Windows server getting 404 with Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a windows server that is used to host a portfolio site and some applications, The website works on ports 80 and 443 using nginx.

I'm trying to get nginx to reverse proxy some of my applications to help secure them a bit more.

Following all the guides my website is still up and running but the apps are still only reachable via their assigned ports.

The SSL nginx currently looks like :

```
 server {
    listen       192.168.0.2:443;
    server_name  example.com 192.168.0.2;

    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  key.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /app1/ {
        proxy_set_header Host 192.168.0.2:3882/;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.2:3882/app1;
    }

    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3883;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

}

I've tried 2 different ways to try and see the apps but both methods produce a 404 not found, the error log shows the following error:

```
2019/09/10 22:21:08 [error] 11940#15356: *1 CreateFile() "C:\Users\Alex\Services\nginx-1.17.3/html/app1" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified), client: 192.168.0.2, server: example.com, request: "GET /app1 HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.2"
```

From the error all I could deduce is that nginx is looking inside the website folder rather then the server for the app as I see no reference to the port.

I assume the error is somewhere around :

`location /app2 {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3883;`

Where the location might need more information

Comment: The error specifies the URI as `/app1` which matches your `location /` block.

Comment: the error is present for /app1 and /app2  which are both present on the server but not in the location of the webiste so from the error i think its trying to look in the website folder not the server itself i think once ive got out by something like location ^~/app1 it would work but this did nothing to fix the error as it was still looking in the website folder